# Is this implementation of a mobile nav menu just not compatible with IOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

The code I have written to create an animated mobile navigation menu doesn't work on IOS. Instead of a smooth and fluent animation, it is extremely laggy and doesn't draw the menu. I have tested it on two iPhones running the latest software.

When viewed in chrome on Windows, safari on MacOS and chrome on android the menu works as supposed to.

The website is hosted at https://strathrowing.daniellowry.co.uk/

I've already tried adding --webkit prefix to clip-path.

The code is in this repository on GitHub: https://github.com/dandyrow/StrathRowing/